# Laravel access foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I am new on coding can you help me with accessing this I am stuck here:

```
foreach($questions_answers as $correct) {
    dd($correct->answers);
}
```

[image]

And this is what I am getting so far but I want to access correct how can I achieve that..?

Answer (score 1):

You loop over the items in the collection and then you can access the individual properties:

```
foreach($questions_answers as $questions_answer) {
    dd($questions_answer->correct);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to do another loop inside..?!

Comment: No you have a collection of `Answer` items, so looping the collection will iterate each `Answer` model. You can then access the model attributes that way.

Comment: Yea but I used foreach of questions and then the collection of answers appeared..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach ($questions_answers as $correct) {
    foreach ($correct->answers as $answer) {
        if ($answer->correct == 1) {
            dd($answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea its foreach($questions_answers as $correct) {
    dd($correct->answers);
}

Comment: Have you got your expected value?

Comment: Somebody incorrectly flagged your answer as low-quality. You should add some accompanying text to explain how your answer works to prevent further flagging. A code-only answer [is not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag as 'not an answer' or recommend deletion (if in the review queue). b) Is it technically incorrect? Downvote or comment. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18801308).